# Cron and SetTimeZone in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, cron

just wondering if someone could help point me in the right direction.

We have a feed, times are in UTC.

We wish to amend these times to 'Europe/London' before insertion into DB

Server is using BST (centos 6.8), PHP version 5.5

php.ini has been set in the local root to 'Europe/London'

In the php file itself, we are using

```
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
```

This is working fine when I load the php file in the browser window, it's amending the time difference to Europe/London

But the cron job just ignores the SetTimezone and inserts as normal in UTC.

I have tried changing the php.ini to UTC, that still doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the bellow code before runing the code in cron job.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
```

It will set the time zone at that particular instance of code

Comment: Unfortunately not, still storing as UTC times.

Comment: will check in my server and let you know

Comment: Hi Nishant, I was calling an include in the file as well, and I put your line in that one as well, this seems to have cured my issue. thank you :)

Comment: Good to know  :) happy coding